# Family use in glm in R for index's

Tags: generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation, exponential-family

I have a set of fluctuating asymmetry indices data sheets and would like to run a GLM using this index as the dependent variable and the other characteristics of the sheet as predictor variables (sheet width, thickness of the sheet).
the variable response is the index ranging from 0 to 0.83. that is, a continuous variable. I can not use the gamma family for having 0 values, I can not use the negative binomial family because the values are not integers. Would anyone know which family is the most suitable?

```r
m1 <- glm.nb(IND ~ ALT + ESP + FORM + LOCAL + FILO + AREA, 
              link="log", data = amostra)
warnings ( In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.110000)
```

Comment: This is in danger of being closed as you seem to be asking for code help although I think you have a statistical question here. Are the zeroes all genuine zeroes or are they just below the threshold of your measuring device?

Comment: Ouch! Sorry.  Are genuine zeros. the leaves was measured with imageJ

Comment: Since you have genuine zeros you could contemplate zero-inflation models, for instance zero-inflated gamma